# Need substitute for using Cross Apply with SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote the following script that works fine in my SQL Server 2008 developer database using the CROSS APPLY parameter but it will not work for the client who has a SQL Server 2000 database and does not want to change the compatibility setting in SSMS.

Can someone suggest a way to convert my script below so as not to use the CROSS APPLY parameter? Thanks!

```
DECLARE @Flag INT
SET @Flag = 1
WHILE (@Flag < (SELECT TOP 1 (COUNT(CUSTOMERPN)) AS COUNTCUST FROM FC_Nestle
GROUP BY CustomerPN
ORDER BY COUNTCUST DESC))
BEGIN
--UPDATE AFS_TOPRODUCE COUNTS
UPDATE FC_Nestle
SET AFS_ToProduce = CustReqQty - AFS_OH
--UPDATE SUBSEQUENT AFS_OH INVENTORY COUNTS
update FC_Nestle 
set AFS_OH = - fc2.AFS_ToProduce 
from FC_Nestle 
CROSS APPLY 
(   
    select fc2.AFS_ToProduce   
    from    
    (     
        select top 1         
            fc2.AFS_ToProduce       
        from FC_Nestle fc2      
        where fc2.ForecastID < FC_Nestle.ForecastID and fc2.CustomerPN = FC_Nestle.CustomerPN     
        order by fc2.ForecastID desc   
    ) fc2   
    where fc2.AFS_ToProduce < 0 
) fc2 
where FC_Nestle.AFS_ToProduce > 0 
SET @Flag = @Flag + 1
END
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Oh man, you really shouldn't reuse the aliases you are giving to your derived tables, I count three different `fc2` tables on the same query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should help you out:

```
update fc_test
   set AFS_OH = - fc2.AFS_ToProduce
  from fc_test
 -- Self join to find previous row
 inner join fc_test fc2
 -- which has lower forecastid
    on fc2.ForecastID < fc_test.ForecastID
 where fc_test.AFS_ToProduce > 0
 -- and negative afs_toproduce
   and fc2.afs_toproduce < 0
 -- and is a row immediately before
 -- ie there is no other row closer to fc_test then current fc2
   and not exists (select null 
                     from fc_test fc3
                    where fc3.forecastid > fc2.forecastid
                      and fc3.ForecastID < fc_test.ForecastID)
```

I'm using the same table and column names as last time.

Live test is at [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00879/10).

Comment: Yes, I remember you helping me last time. Do I need to place this within my While loop or just run it as you have it here?

Comment: I ran the script within the loop and it didn't modify any records. I looked through the code but I don't see anything obvious to me. Thanks again Nikola!

Comment: @ToddS The idea was to replace original update with this one, but you should replace table names with real ones and add CustomerPN filter. And you are welcome :-)